# KeyError: 'pdb_use_exclamation_mark' in Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I just started my project this morning, which I left last evening. I was about to debug the code which was running yesterday evening without any changes.

I'm receiving this error: `KeyError: 'pdb_use_exclamation_mark'`
This error is referencing to the beginning of the file where nothing has changed since I started my project. It looks like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Mon Nov 23 11:39:04 2020

@author: name
"""
import os
```

And so on...

Any ideas on how to solve this? Haven't seen anything similar on the web, what might help.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Please open the Anaconda Prompt (or your terminal in other operating systems) and run `conda install spyder-kernels=1.9.4`. That should fix your problem.

Comment: oh yeah solved it! Thanks!

Comment: Great! I'll add it as answer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) If you're using Anaconda, please close Spyder, open the Anaconda Prompt (on Windows) or a system terminal (on Linux or Mac) and run

`conda install spyder-kernels=1.9.4`

Then start Spyder again. That will fix your problem.

Comment: if I'm using a virtual env, shall I run the code above in side the virtual env or in the base one? Im facing tons of Spyder issues with virtual environments \